# Cannot use virtual env

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, homebrew

I am on a Mac OS X Yosemite. I have anaconda installed on my computer, and when I make a new virtualenv with `virtualenv foo`, I get error:

```
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lingxiao/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/lingxiao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/lingxiao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Users/lingxiao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Users/lingxiao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/lingxiao/Docu...board/foo/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Is this because of Anaconda? when I do `which python`  I see

```
/Users/myname/anaconda/bin/python
```

and when I list `brew list python` I see:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/2to3
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/2to3-2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/2to3-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/idle
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/idle2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/idle2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pydoc
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pydoc2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pydoc2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pythonw
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pythonw2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pythonw2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/smtpd.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/smtpd2.7.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/smtpd2.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/ (2102 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/IDLE.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/libexec/pip/ (291 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/libexec/setuptools/ (152 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/libexec/wheel/ (54 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Python Launcher.app/Contents/ (17 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/share/man/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/share/python/ (315 files)
```

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/741 and https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367, which suggest something about [The best solution I know of now is to downgrade to python 2.7.9.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367#issuecomment-263964339)

Comment: @downshift if you post that as an answer I can check solved for you

Comment: I only posted it as a comment because it possibly would not be the same solution, did you try downgrade to python 2.7.9 and you are now able to make virtual environments?

Comment: yeah that fixed it.

Comment: Okay cool, I don't know if it's a legitimate answer, but I'll go ahead and post it anyway since you said it did fix it. Thanks for your feedback @chibro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was related to http://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/741 and http://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367, which suggest [The best solution I know of now is to downgrade to python 2.7.9](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367#issuecomment-263964339), and was confirmed by the OP.